# Unable to Override WooCommerce Checkout Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, user-roles

I've created a custom WooCommerce checkout field with Woothemes Checkout Field Editor labeled "po_number". I would like the PO Number checkout field to only display for the user role "distributor".

So far I've been unsuccessful in overriding the checkout fields. I'm using Wordpress 4.5.1 / Woocommerce 2.5.5. Here's the code I've placed in my child theme's **`functions.php`**. I've also tested to make sure it is not a theme conflict.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'distributor' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['po_number'] ) ) {
        unset($fields['billing']['po_number']);

    }
     return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `current_user_can()` function is related to capabilities of the user roles, but not to detect the user roles themselves. For that reason is not working in your code.

You need to set a conditional function for this purpose (user roles):

```
function is_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    } else {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    }
    if ( empty( $user ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles ) == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can use that function:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if ( !is_user_role( 'distributor' ) && isset( $fields['billing']['po_number'] ) ) {
        unset($fields['billing']['po_number']);
    }
        return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

This should work in your code.